# Using Gridster in Multiple Tab?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular-gridster2

I want to create multiple dashboards using using angular-gridster2 in angular 8. I have multiple tabs having gridster in each Tab. I am facing these issues for multiple tabs.

- lets say that tab1 gridster has 3 items & tab2 gridster has 2 item
  and i am at tab one initially when I move from tab1 to tab2 initially
  it is not showing any item in gridster when I add one more item in
  gridster of tab2 then i will all the 3 items of gridster of tab2.
- Updating the display grid property of options is updating only the
  last gridster item. I want to apply same options properties to all
  the gridster present along multiple tabs.

[You can see the gridster along multiple tab here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4velr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems I have found.

It looks like in the addItem() method, you are adding new item directly to 0 indexed gridster, if you want to keep gridsters separate you must pass the index of the gridster or a pointer in a way to the related gridster.

```
 addItem(){
     this.gridsters[0].... // change 0 with an index
}
```

I am not sure about this one, I am a bit rusty with Angular but it looks like you didn't separate the tab-contents. You might wanna add tab-content to each tab.

You might want to consider encapsulating your components, maybe use angular components. With the current way, your code can get really messy after a while and will be very hard to handle

Comment: thanks for your time. In addItem() I am statically adding component gridster item to both gridster dashboard.

Comment: Ohh yeah, you are right. I must have deleted that line while I was debugging. Sorry for the confusion.